# Ruby on Rails - jQuery.countdown no display

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, countdown, jquery-countdown

Before I move to RoR I was using this great [jQuery countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) and it worked fine.
I try to use it again in my Rails (4.0.8) application but I can't figure it why nothing is displayed.

I have in app/assets/javascripts (among others) :

```
application.js
jquery.countdown.min.js
jquery-2.1.1.min.js
```

In my application.js :

```
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery-2.1.1.min
//= require jquery.countdown.min
```

In my Gemfile :

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
```

In my app/views/pages/page.html.erb :

```
<br />
--
<div data-countdown="2016/01/01"></div>
--

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
   $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
     $this.html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
   });
 });
</script>
```

Like [documented on this page](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples/multiple-instances.html) but nothing shows up.

[image: No_display_countdown]

Am I missing something obvious ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to display my countdown again !

I found (printing the javascript console) that I have the error `$ is not defined`. So I remove `gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'` from my Gemfile and perform the command `gem uninstall jquery-rails`. Then I added those few lines in my header and restarted the server.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-2.1.1.min" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.countdown.min" %>
```